# What is the purpose of the "ipam" key in a Docker Compose config?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am new to Docker but not so new I don't understand the cli of Docker. However I am very new to the Docker file and Docker Compose way of doing things. If someone could explain to me this section of the docker-compose.yml I would greatly appreciate it.

My comments are embedded:

```
networks:
  vpcbr: <-I know what this is
    driver: bridge <-I know what this is
    ipam:  <-What the heck is this for?
     config: <-I know what this is.
       - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16 <- Obvious
         gateway: 10.5.0.1 <- Obvious
```

Comment: Ipam stands for ip address management. It's the section of the config file where you pass the next couple ip settings.

Comment: I know this is wayy tooo late, but incase someone comes along - 'vpcbr' is the name of the network, can be anything. One of my networks is called "bnet" (totally random).

Answer (score 39):

IPAM is the name of configuration section.

IPAM is an acronym, that stands for IP Address Management.

see more here: https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-networking-design-philosophy

Comment: This blog post is so lengthy and has so little actual information. I wonder how people have so much patience.

Comment: Archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20220320062451/https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-networking-design-philosophy/